# Android OnTouchListener Calling Wrong View

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener, android-seekbar

I have two views in my activity in my Android app. One View (we'll call this `viewOne`) has a bunch of `SeekBars` while the other view (we'll call this `viewTwo`) contains a `Drawable` that is redrawn whenever a user touches it.

`viewTwo` has an `OnTouchListener`. The issue is that when I touch `viewOne` to move a `SeekBar`, `viewTwo`'s touch listener is getting called and this creates a huge amount of lag due to it needing to redraw every time the listener is called.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Main Activity Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <com.rfoo.viewOne
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.5"
          android:id="@+id/vOne"/>

     <com.rfoo.viewTwo
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.5"
          android:id="@+id/vTwo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

View One Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <SeekBar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.25"
          android:id="@+id/sb1"/>

     <SeekBar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.25"
          android:id="@+id/sb2"/>

     <SeekBar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.25"
          android:id="@+id/sb3"/>

     <SeekBar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.25"
          android:id="@+id/sb4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

View Two Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/myView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // Initializations here...
         // And then:
         View viewTwo = (View)findViewById(R.id.vTwo);
         viewTwo.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.vTwo) {
            vTwo.invalidate();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give more details, paste your code with that limited information is hard to find out the cause.

Comment: @JuanHurtado Alright added code, I didn't add everything from my `MainActivity` class but basically I set an `OnTouchListener` to my second view and I never set `OnTouchListener` to my first view's java class file

Answer (score 0):

You implemented View.OnTouchListener but you haven't used it. I think your purpose is using that to trigger onTouch()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // Initializations here...
         // And then:
         View viewTwo = (View)findViewById(R.id.vTwo);
         viewTwo.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
              @Override
              public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.vTwo) { // you can  use viewTwo instead of v   as well
                          viewTwo.invalidate();
                    }
              }
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry! I put in the wrong code! Check the above for the revision. That still doesn't answer the question why View One is getting called when I'm following this process: (1) Touch View Two (2) `onTouch` is called (3) Move a Seekbar (4) `onTouch` is called once again but says View Two is being touched...

Answer (score 0):

Well i am almost sure the problem is because the unused nested layouts i tried this and worked fine for me :

```
public class exampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Motion event";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.myView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (v.getId() == R.id.myView) &&
                        handleGesture(MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event));
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean handleGesture(int action) {
        switch(action) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                return true;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                        "of current screen element");
                return true;
            default :
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:id="@+id/sb1"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/sb2"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/sb3"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/sb4"/>

    <View
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/appframe__colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/myView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will only be called when R.id.vTwo is clicked, let me know if it works, btw try to remove useless layouts on you xml (makes view load slower)

Comment: Hey Juan, thanks for the answer. I would use onclicklistener but I also need to detect finger movement so ontouch is a must

Comment: Why do you call `findViewById` twice?

Comment: Sorry was a typo i just fix it